# Creating reusable text field component using Material UI and react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I was trying to develop reusable text field component using Material UI and reach-hook-form. I was referring following examples:

- **Example 1** <sup>[ref](https://react-hook-form.com/ts#UseFormReturn)</sup>**:**

  ```
    type FormProps<TFormValues> = {
      onSubmit: SubmitHandler<TFormValues>;
      children: (methods: UseFormReturn<TFormValues>) => React.ReactNode;
    };

    const Form = <TFormValues extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>({
      onSubmit,
      children
    }: FormProps<TFormValues>) => {
      const methods = useForm<TFormValues>();
      return (
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>{children(methods)}</form>
      );
    };
  ```
- **Example 2** <sup>[ref](https://github.com/Mohammad-Faisal/react-hook-form-material-ui)</sup>**:**

  ```
   //https://github.com/Mohammad-Faisal/react-hook-form-material-ui/blob/master/src/form-components/FormInputProps.ts

   export interface FormInputProps {
     name: string;
     control: any;
     label: string;
     setValue?: any;
   }

   //https://github.com/Mohammad-Faisal/react-hook-form-material-ui/blob/master/src/form-components/FormInputText.tsx

   import React from "react";
   import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
   import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
   import { FormInputProps } from "./FormInputProps";

   export const FormInputText = ({ name, control, label }: FormInputProps) => {
     return (
       <Controller
         name={name}
         control={control}
         render={({
           field: { onChange, value },
           fieldState: { error },
           formState,
         }) => (
           <TextField
             helperText={error ? error.message : null}
             size="small"
             error={!!error}
             onChange={onChange}
             value={value}
             fullWidth
             label={label}
             variant="outlined"
           />
         )}
       />
     );
   };
  ```

After analyzing both, I came up with following:

```
 import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
 import { Controller, UseFormReturn } from "react-hook-form";

 interface IRhfTextBoxProps<TFormValues> {
   name: string;
   methods: UseFormReturn<TFormValues>;
 }

 // export const RhfTextBox = <TFormValues extends unknown>(props : IRhfTextBoxProps<TFormValues>) => {  //##1
 export const RhfTextBox = <TFormValues extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>(  // ##2 similar to example 1
   props: IRhfTextBoxProps<TFormValues>
 ) => {
   return (
     <Controller
       control={props.methods.control}
       name={props.name}  // ##3
       render={({ field, fieldState, formState }) => (
         <TextField
           error={!!fieldState.error}
           helperText={fieldState.error?.message ?? ""}
           key={props.name}
         />
       )}
     />
   );
 };
```

Both lines `##1` and `##2` in above code gives following  error at line `##3`:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Path<TFormValues>'.
```

The detailed error message is as follows:

```
The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { render: ({ field, fieldState, formState, }: { field: ControllerRenderProps<TFormValues, Path<TFormValues>>; fieldState: ControllerFieldState; formState: UseFormStateReturn<...>; }) => ReactElement<...>; } & UseControllerProps<...>'
```

**Q1.** Why am I getting this error?
**Q2.** Should I just use non generics `FormInputProps` as in example 2, instead of generics based `FormProps` in example 1.

Answer (score 0):

**This is my component, it works well for what I need.**

```
type TextInputProps = {...

export default function TextInput(props: TextInputProps) {
  const {
    name = '',
    label,
    type = 'text',
    size = 'small',
    variant = 'outlined',
    placeholder = '',
    fullWidth = false,
    className = 'my-2',
    disabled = false,
    multiline = false,
    rows = 1,
    maxRows = 4,
    maxLength = 99999,
    validators = {},
    style,
  } = props;
  const { control, register } = useFormContext();

  const getInputHelperText = useCallback((error) => {
    return !error ? '' : error.message || getFormErrorMessage(error.type);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field: { value }, fieldState }) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...register(name, validators)}
            className={className}
            value={value}
            label={label}
            error={!!fieldState.invalid}
            helperText={!fieldState.invalid ? '' : getInputHelperText(fieldState.error)}
            disabled={disabled}
            fullWidth={fullWidth}
            variant={variant}
            size={size}
            multiline={multiline}
            rows={rows || 1}
            maxRows={maxRows}
            type={type}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

**I invoke my component this way..**

```
 <TextInput
    label='field Name'
    name='field'
    placeholder='placeholder'
    fullWidth
    validators={{
      required: true,
    }}
  />
```

This form i have access to all features this two worlds.
I can sand default values through useForm, get errors, watch change and etc...